# A book has a few pages on which page numbers are written. Someone has torn one page out of it and now average of all page numbers is $\frac{105}{4}$

Tags: number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I couldn't relate this question to any of the topics specifically , I found this in a miscellaneous math problems book(non-calculus) .
 Here's how it goes,
  A book has a few pages on which page numbers are written. Someone has torn one page out of it and now average of all page numbers is $\frac{105}{4}$. Answer the following:

(i) If the total numbers of pages in book is n then find the value of

$$\sum_{r=1}^{10} \biggl\lfloor{\frac{n+r}{r+1}}\biggr\rfloor\,.$$

 OPTIONS: 
(A)100 (B)107 (C)105 (D)82

(ii) If the line $x+y=\bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigr\rfloor$ is drawn ,then the total number of points with integral co-ordinates enclosed within the region bounded by $x=0,y=0$ and $x+y=\bigl\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\bigr\rfloor$ is -----?

(A)105 (B)153 (C)59 (D)78 

STATUS: No clue how to start.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why don't you write instead "A book has its pages numbered"? the way yo state the problem suggest that numbers are written *inside* the pages, and so such numbers have nothing to do with the respective page numbers.

Comment: OK, I cannot make much sense of it: if page number $x$ has been torn out of a book with $n$ pages the average of the remaining page numbers will be $\frac{105}{4}=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-x\right)$ which then can be rewritten to $x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{105}{4}(n-1)$. The first fraction is the triangular number and always yield an integer so $n-1$ has to be divisible by 4 for $x$ to be an integer. But it is easy to check that $x$ is a quadratic expression in $n$ that is negative for $1<n<50$ and exceeds $n$ for $n>52$. But $n=51$ does NOT have $n-1$ divisible by 4.

Comment: If the average is $105\over 4$, then I would assume that for $n$ the total number of pages and $r$ the number of pages with the page number written on them, that this average implies that $4|r$.  What does this observation tell you about the problem?

Comment: ...continuing from above... So either $n=1$ which seems strange or I am way off trying to understand what you wrote.

Comment: If a page is torn out of a book, that disposes of two page numbers. Depending on the numbering scheme, the normal arrangement is that the lower of the two numbers is odd, so we lose page numbers $2r-1$ and $2r$.

Comment: @Simar+MarkBennet: That was too bad. With Mark Bennets suggestion I made it work for $n=50$ so that the book has page numbers $7$ and $8$ removed and the remaining $48$ pages have an average of $\frac{1}{48}\left(\frac{50\cdot 51}{2}-7-8\right)=\frac{105}{4}$.

Comment: @String I still can't get it . Can you post the answer? , do have a look at the options ,I've edited the post.

Comment: @String how did you solve for two variables in a single equation? I mean its alright if you made it work but we should have a second equation if this question is meant to be solved ,where does that come from ?

Comment: You can only solve for two variables in one equation if some additional restrictions are there. Here $x$ and $n$ has to be positive integers with $x<n$. That makes the whole difference. See the answer I posted...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so here is a solution to (i) in case we know that when a page is torn out and odd and the following even page number is removed.

Given the book has $n$ pages the sum of the page numbers will be
$$
T_n=1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
known as the $n$'th Triangular Number. So assume that page numbers $x$ and $x+1$ have been torn out where $x$ is odd. Then we can write
$$
\frac{105}{4}=\tfrac{1}{n-2}\left(T_n-(2x+1)\right)
$$
Plugging in the formula for $T_n$ from above and solving for $x$ then yields
$$
x=\frac{1}{4}n^2-\frac{103}{8}n+\frac{103}{4}
$$
which is a quadratic expression in $n$ with zeros $n=\frac{103\pm\sqrt{8961}}{4}$ which approximately is $n=2.08$ and $n=49.42$. On the other hand it is obvious that $x<n$ which then in turn yields a quadratic inequality in $n$ that can be solved to see that $n<\frac{111+\sqrt{10673}}{4}\approx 53.58$.

Having a slightly closer look at the expression for $x$ one realizes that $n-2$ must be divisible by $8$ for $x$ to be an integer. So unless we take $n=2$ (which actually works) we must have $49.42<n=50<53.58$ for $n$ to be an integer satisfying all requirements in that interval. Plugging $n=50$ into the expression for $x$ then yields $x=7,x+1=8$, and you can check as I did in the comments that the average of the remaining pages is really $\frac{105}{4}$. With $n=50$ one gets
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left\lfloor\frac{50+r}{r+1}\right\rfloor=105
$$
So option (C) answers the first question correctly.

### Part (ii)

Still using $n=50$ we get $\lfloor\frac{50}{3}\rfloor=16$ so that the line is $x+y=16$ or $y=16-x$. Together with the axes $y=0$ and $x=0$ this encloses a triangle with $17$ lattice points on the line $y=16-x$ since you can start from $(0,16)$ and move down right step-by-step to 'visit' 17 lattice points before you hit the x-axis. Similarly you hit $16$ lattice points following the same procedure from $(0,15)$. With this we get the answer to (ii) which is:
$$
T_{17}=17+16+...+1=\frac{17\cdot 18}{2}=153
$$
So option (B) answers the second question correctly.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**More on how to deduce the value of $n$.** The average page number before a page is torn is

$$ \frac{1+2+\cdots+n}{n}=\frac{n+1}{2}$$

Since two consecutive page numbers are removed, let the two page numbers be $2k-1$ and $2k$, where $2\le 2k\le n$, then

$$\begin{align}
n\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}-(n-2)\frac{105}{4} =& 2k-1+2k\\
\frac{n}{2}(n+1)-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)\left(52+\frac{1}{2}\right) =& 4k-1
\end{align}$$

Since $\frac{n}{2}$ and $k$ are integers, to make the above left hand side an integer, we must have $\frac{n}{2}-1$ even, or $\frac{n}{2}$ is an odd number. Let $n=4m+2$, where $m$ is an integer.

$$\begin{align}
(2m+1)(4m+2+1)-105m+1 =& 4k
\end{align}$$

Again, since $m$ and $k$ are integers, to make the above left hand side an even number, $m$ must be an even number. Let $m=2p$, where $p$ is an integer. Then $n=8p+2$.

$$\begin{align}
(4p+1)(8p+3)-210p+1 =& 4k\\
32p^2-190p+4 =& 4k
\end{align}$$

Again, since $p$ and $k$ are integers, to make the above left hand side a multiple of 4, $p$ must be an even number. Let $p=2q$, where $q$ is an integer. Then $n=16q+2$.

$$\begin{align}
128q^2-380q+4 =& 4k\\
32q^2-95q+1 =& k
\end{align}$$

Considering the conditions for the value of $k$,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
2 \le& 2k &\le n\\
2 \le& 2(32q^2-95q+1) &\le 16q+2\\
0 \le& 2q(32q- 95) &\le 16q\\
0 \le& 32q- 95 &\le 8\\
95 \le& 32q &\le 103\\
3-\frac{1}{32} \le& q &\le 3+\frac{7}{32}\\
\end{array}$$

Therefore, we only have

$$\begin{align}
q =& 3\\
n =& 16q+2 = 50\\
2k=& 8\\
2k-1 =& 7
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As the average is 105/4 ,the total number of pages would be a multiple of 4.
so lets take the total number of pages after 1page is torn will be 4m.

Now the total number of pages will be 4m+2(1 page consists of 2 numbers)

As we know that average will be near to the middle number of the series.
let's take 4m =  48     (26+1/4)

now 4m+2= 50

total number of pages after 1page torn is 48*150/4 =1260
and actual number of pages would be 50*51/2 =1275

Now the difference will be 15.

as one page is torn the numbers on that be lets say n and n+1.

now n=7 and n+1 =8

so the page that is torn is containing 7 and 8

Answer (score -1):

For 1, we have to assume the pages are  consecutively numbered from $1$ to $n$ before a single page is removed (which removes two page numbers).  The average of all the page numbers is $\frac {n+1}2$.  The remaining number of pages must be a multiple of $4$ so we can get the denominator in the average. Clearly it will not move the average much, so the average is about $26$ and $n$ is about twice that.  So we guess $n=54$ will work.  The sum of all the pages is $\frac {54 \cdot 55}2=1485$.  The sum of the remaining pages if $52 \cdot \frac {105}4=1365$, so the sum of the removed page numbers is $120$.  Unfortunately there is no page with that sum.  Trying $n=50$ gives a starting sum of $1275$ and an ending sum of $1260$, leading to removal of the page that includes numbers $12$ and $13$.  It is then arithmetic to evaluate the sum, getting $105$

An approach without guessing, but with more work is as follows:  If we let $m$ be the page number removed, we have $$\frac {\frac {n(n+1)}2-m}{n-1}=\frac {105}4\\
\frac {n(n+1)}2-m=\frac {105(n-1)}4\\2n^2+2n-4m=105n-105\\2n^2-103n+105-4m=0\\n=\frac 14\left(103 +\sqrt{103^2+32m-620}\right)$$ and searching for $m$ that will make the square root an integer will get there.

Comment: How can you remove page 66 from a 53-page book?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki LOL ! Exactly .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  I didn't think about the fact that you pull two page numbers, but there is still a problem.  Fixed now.